# Fragment and viewLifecycleOwner deviation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm collecting a flow on the `viewLifecycleOwner`. It flows on `Dispatchers.Default`, but the collection itself takes place on `Dispatchers.Main`.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        flow.flowOn(Default).collect {
            requireContext()
        }
    }
}
```

In one occation I found the `IllegalStateException` stating, that the fragment is not attached.

> IllegalStateException: Fragment Test not attached to a context.

I assumed that the collection of the flow would be canceled before the fragment is detached.

How is it possible for the coroutine to resume on a detached fragment?

Comment: I am not familiar with `FLOW` . Since `lifecycleScope` is co routine scope it will be destroyed when component destroyed.  can we have a check `if(parentScope.isActive)` for in the inner scope collection ?

Comment: @ADM I don't know about a reproduction yet. I'll add more logging for the future, but I don't know when it'll happen again...

Comment: As per my understanding `IllegalStateException` indicates that even though lifecycleScope is destroyed the internal Scope which continues to Execute that's why i suggested `if(parentScope.isActive)` . Can't we simple pass `Dispatcher` to `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch` maybe `Dispatcher,IO` and collect the flow directly in this way there will be only one scope . Will that work with Flow ?

Comment: @ADM the collection needs to resume on `Main`. The flow itself is a dependency and `flowOn` is set on it before as well. The `IllegalStateException` indicates that the lifecycle is after `onDetach`. Might it be possible that the collector was dispatched and therefore the Runnable enqueued on `Main`, just before the fragment was destroyed? I think `isActive` might be an important information to observe. Sadly I was just notified, that the crash was not observed by the user. So maybe it's related to an app update or process shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is worth noting that `flowOn` changes the upstream context, in case you have operator functions such as `map`, `filter`, *etc*, preceding to the `flowOn`. So, it doesn't affect the context of the terminal functions like `collect`. It is stated on the [kotlin docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow-on.html). So, if you want to change the context of the `collect` terminal, you should change it from the outer block, I mean the `launch` builder function.

Next, to avoid `IllegalStateException` use `context` in a safe manner, instead of `requireContext()` to be sure that the fragment is attached. There is no doubt that all of the coroutines launched in the `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` should be terminated when the fragment is getting destroyed, but in some cases, there might exist a race condition in threads which causes this problem.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch(Main/Default/WhateverContextYouWant) {
        flow.collect {
            context?.let { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an option, sadly. The flow needs to flow on `Default`, while the collection needs to suspend on `Main`. `requireContext()` itself is called indirectly. I could check, if the Fragment is still attached, but more I'd like to trust the scope to cancel the collection or at least understand, why something was resumed while it should have been canceled.

Comment: Cold-flow in kotlin supports back-pressure, so offering values is entirely independent of collection. So, the context that you are offering values on the flow does not affect the collection. You can emit values on `IO` or `Default` context, but collect them on `Main`. Therefore, if you want values to be flown on `Default` you should do it where the flow is defined (and values are emitted) as opposed to where the collection is.

Comment: Theoretically, we have to rely on what we're told, I mean when a scope is canceled, all the running coroutines will be canceled too. But the thing is there might be rare exceptions in timing, I think.